# Add glow effect to text of a UI button - swift

Tags: swift, button, glow

my question is quite straight forward. I am aiming to add a basic glow effect to a button in swift. I want the text to glow, not the entire button box. 
I have attached an image as an example to illustrate what I am aiming to achieve.[image: Image in Agency FB font with a yellow glow effect.]

I have looked elsewhere but typically only find animations which is not what I want. Sorry the image is of poor quality.

I am currently using this code but my settings button appears with a very weak glow, how can I make it stronger:

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    enum GlowEffect: Float {
        case small = 0.4, normal = 2, big = 30
    }

    func doGlowAnimation(withColor color: UIColor, withEffect effect: GlowEffect = .normal) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = 0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = .zero

        let glowAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowRadius")
        glowAnimation.fromValue = 20 // effect.rawValue
        glowAnimation.toValue = 20
        glowAnimation.fillMode = .removed
        glowAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        layer.add(glowAnimation, forKey: "shadowGlowingAnimation")
    }
}
```

Changing the intensity doesn't give that strong color effect near the individual letters

Answer (score 2):

To create an outer glow effect on the title of a `UIButton` you'll want to make sure you adjust the shadow properties of the `UIButton`'s `titleLabel`. Meaning you could run your animation by saying:

```
button.titleLabel?.doGlowAnimation(withColor: UIColor.yellow)
```

The animation adjusts `shadowRadius` though currently goes from `20` to `20` so there's no actual animation.

```
extension UIView {
    enum GlowEffect: Float {
        case small = 0.4, normal = 2, big = 30
    }

    func doGlowAnimation(withColor color: UIColor, withEffect effect: GlowEffect = .normal) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowRadius = 0
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        layer.shadowOffset = .zero

        let glowAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowRadius")
        glowAnimation.fromValue = 0
        glowAnimation.toValue = effect.rawValue
        glowAnimation.fillMode = .removed
        glowAnimation.repeatCount = .infinity
        glowAnimation.duration = 2
        glowAnimation.autoreverses = true
        layer.add(glowAnimation, forKey: "shadowGlowingAnimation")
    }
}
```

Provides a pulsating outer glow, growing over the course of two seconds then reversing.

Comment: How do you keep the glow effect once the animation is done?